# Azure DevOps - AWS CloudFormation and parameters

Tags: azure-devops, aws-cloudformation

I have a simple CloudFomration template to create a VPC:

```
vpc.yaml
---
Parameters:
  CidrBlock:
    Type: String
    Description: The primary IPv4 CIDR block for the VPC

Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::VPC"
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref "CidrBlock"
      Tags:
      - Key: "Name"
        Value: "This is the main VPC"
```

In my Azure Devops pipleline I want to use AWS Stack create to create a VPC by using this CloudFormation template.

```
Azure-pipeline.yaml
---
jobs:
- job: Job1
  steps:
  - task: CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack@1
    inputs:
      awsCredentials: 'My-cred'
      regionName: 'ap-southeast-2'
      stackName: 'Stack1'
      templateSource: 'file'
      templateFile: 'vpc.yaml'
      templateParametersSource: inline
      templateParameters: |
        - ParameterKey: CidrBlock
          ParameterValue: '10.10.10.0/24'
```

Obviousely, it'll work fine when I manually provide the value for the CidrBlock parameter when calling vpc.yaml template (like above ^). But what I want to do is using another file to store the parameters and values and pass that when running the vpc template.
In other words, I have a params.yaml file in which I stored the required parameters to run vpc.yaml. How can I use that when running the vpc.yaml template as the parameter files?

```
params.yaml
---
parameters:
- name: CidrBlock
  value: '10.10.10.0/24'
```

Like how I refer to the template file in azure-pipeline file above, is there a similar way with which I can refer to the params file instead of using ***templateParametersSource: inline*** ?

Comment: Sounds like I can use templateParametersSource: 'file' and templateParametersFile: 'params.yaml'. So now when I run my pipeline it gives me the following error: ##[error]InvalidParameterType: Expected params.Parameters to be an Array. Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like unlike Azure Bicep or ARM where you can use keys of your own when creating the params files, AWS expect a specific structure where you must always use **ParameterKey** and **ParameterValue** as the key.
Here is how the params file should look like in my case:

```
---
- ParameterKey: CidrBlock
  ParameterValue: '10.10.10.0/24'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an issue with YAML parameters file with aws-cli:

https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2275

You can use JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "CidrBlock": "10.10.10.0/24",
  }
]
```